Quel est le bon terme francophone pour le 'Football'?
Le terme Football est pas mal toujours utilisé pour nommer le sport que les américains appellent le 'Soccer'.
C'est évidemment un anglicisme.
Mais y a-t-il un terme francophone pour nommer ce sport? Un mot maintenant oublié qui était utilisé avant que l'anglicisme prenne la place?

Jeu de balle au pied? ;-) Mais tout le monde dit "foot" maintenant, même pas "football", c'est trop long.

Le football (très exactement football association) est une importation anglaise, le jeu a été importé avec son nom.

Je trouve balle au pied ; apparement désuet.
https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/balle_au_pied
Prononc. et Orth. : [futbo:l], [fut]. On note ds Vie Lang., 1960, p. 390 : ,,La Commission du Vocabulaire sportif ne juge pas souhaitable de franciser ce mot [football] qui est le terme officiel employé par la Fédération. En revanche, on emploiera footballeur de préférence à footballer`` (qui est cependant proposé ds Rob.). Pour Dupré 1972, la prononc. [futbal] qui est ressentie comme pop. serait néanmoins une heureuse francisation. La docum. donne des ex. de foot-ball (cf. Tharaud, An prochain, 1924, p. 22 et Beauvoir, loc. cit.). Étymol. et Hist. 1698 (H. Misson, Mém. et Observ. faites par un Voy. en Anglet., p. 255 d'apr. Mack. t. 1, p. 89); 1728 (C. de Saussure, Lettres et Voyages, p. 298, ibid.), attest. isolées; 1872 contexte angl. (Taine, Notes sur l'Anglet., p. 144 ds Bonn.); 1890 (Lar. 19eSuppl.). Angl. foot(-)ball; v. angl. fut ball, m. angl. foote ball composé de foot « pied » et de ball « balle », attesté dep. 1424 puis 1531. Fréq. abs. littér. : 108. Bbg. Becker (K.). Sportanglizismen im modernen Französisch. Meisenheim, 1970, p. 29, 38, 41, 60, 74, 142. − Bonn. 1920, p. 61. − Boulan 1934, p. 108. − Pauli 1921, p. 63. − Galisson (R.). Rech. de lexicol. descriptive : la banalisation lexicale. Le Vocab. du football dans la presse sportive. Paris, 1978, passim.
https://cnrtl.fr/definition/football

J'imagine donc que en gros, le terme Football a toujours été utilisé, alors même si sa vient de l'anglais, c'est le seul terme francisé pour ce sport (Excepté Soccer, que on utilise au Québec, mais vient aussi de l'anglais.) J'ai fait un peu plus de recherche depuis que j'ai posé la question et en gros, la FIFA (Qui utilise le terme Football en français) a été créé en 1904, à Paris. Alors je crois on peut assumer que sa a toujours été Football.

Comme écrit « La Commission du Vocabulaire sportif ne juge pas souhaitable de franciser ce mot [football] qui est le terme officiel employé par la Fédération. » ce qui veut dire que balle au pied n'est pas et n'a jamais été employé, et si tu le dis on te regardera avec des yeux ronds ! La seule occurrence que je connaisse c'est dans le livre La Balle au pied : Histoire du football (s'il n'y avait l'explication après les deux points, personne ne saurait de quoi il s'agit !). En fait tu ne réponds pas à la question, le terme exact à employer en France est football.

Ils peuvent essayer de le franciser, ça ne marchera jamais. Personne ne va se mettre à dire "allons voir un jeu de la balle au pied!" :-)

Le « bon » terme en France est football mais à l'oral il est très rare qu'on prononce le mot entier. On dit simplement foot : je vais jouer au foot, je vais à un match de foot, une équipe de foot, etc...
On garde par contre souvent football quand il s'agit de locutions officielles : la coupe de monde de football, les instances du football, etc.
On dit aussi jouer au ballon et le sport peut être appelé le ballon rond, souvent par des journalistes, par opposition au ballon ovale (rugby).
Football est parfaitement intégré au lexique français, comme le montrent les dérivés footballeur, footballistique et footeux. En revanche, le footing
n'est pas lié au football, ce mot français est synonyme de jogging.
Avant que les règles du football moderne (Football Association) ne soient établies, on a parfois pu écrire balle au pied mais c'était didactique, destiné à expliquer au lecteurs la signification du mot anglais. Nul n'a probablement jamais dit: « je vais jouer à la balle au pied » contrairement à l'espagnol pour qui un synonyme (rare mais utilisable) de fútbol est balompié.
On peut aussi citer la soule, un jeu apparenté aux ancêtres du football et la barette, mais les deux sont plus proches du rugby.
Ce que les anglophones appellent table-football ou table-soccer est appelé baby-foot en France.
Pour la terminologie québécoise, voir cette réponse.
